# Repositioning the Show/Hide button in an NSOutlineView source list

Tags: swift, cocoa, appkit, nsoutlineview

I'm creating a source list programmatically using an NSOutlineView. Everything works great, except that the Show/Hide buttons on the group rows are positioned too far to the right: their right edge is flush with the right edge of the outline view, instead of being positioned with some margin like I get when I use a NIB.

Poking around in the view hierarchy debugger, I can see that in the version from the NIB, the NSTableRowView and the button have the following constraint: `tableRowView.width = button.maxX + 8 @ 1000`. In my programatic version, the constraint is `tableRowView.width = button.maxX @ 1000`. In both cases, the constraints are created automatically by the outline view or one of its children.

**Is there a way to influence the creation of this constraint so that I get the margin that I'm looking for?**

One wrinkle: I'm not embedding the outline view in an NSScrollView. I'm not sure if this makes a difference. I'm doing this for a somewhat convoluted reason: I'm trying to replicate the sidebar from Music.app, which has a search field that scrolls along with the sidebar. My app is in SwiftUI, so I'm creating an NSViewRepresentable for the outline view, another one for the NSSearchField, and wrapping them both in a SwiftUI ScrollView. I can reproduce the issue without using any SwiftUI.

I've tried a few things:

- I overrode `updateConstraints` on an NSTableRowView subclass in an attempt to update the constraint's constant to 8, but the Show/Hide button has no attached constraints for me to modify when `updateConstraints` is called.
- I overrode `frameOfOutlineCell(atRow:)` on an NSOutlineView subclass, but the button doesn't get moved. It just gets cut off (picture included below).

**Here's what I have (programatic)**

[image: What I have]

**Here's what I want (from a NIB)**

[image: What I want]

**Here's what happens when I override `frameOfOutlineCell(atRow:)`**

[image: What happens when I override frameOfOutlineCell(atRow:)]

Here's the code that creates the outline view:

```swift
func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSOutlineView {
    let outlineView = OutlineView()
    
    outlineView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    outlineView.selectionHighlightStyle = .sourceList
    outlineView.rowSizeStyle = .default
    outlineView.floatsGroupRows = false
    outlineView.focusRingType = .none
    
    let col = NSTableColumn(identifier: .init("Column 0"))
    outlineView.addTableColumn(col)
    outlineView.outlineTableColumn = col
    
    outlineView.delegate = context.coordinator
    outlineView.dataSource = context.coordinator

    outlineView.expandItem(nil, expandChildren: true)
    
    return outlineView
}
```

Comment: It looks like the frame of the button is calculated in `-[NSOutlineView frameOfOutlineCellAtRow:]` and the constraints are added accordingly. Overriding `frameOfOutlineCell(atRow:)` works for me.

Comment: Yes, that did work! Thank you! I had misunderstood what frameOfOutlineCellAtRow was doing. I'll write up a proper answer to this question later today.